# In Jmeter websocket， how can I get several lines of data from the csv file and send these lines one by one or in batch mode to the websocket server

Tags: csv, websocket, jmeter

I just come across a need to send different requests to the WebSocket server, so I use the CSV Data Set Config, but I can get only a line of data from the CSV file. how can I get two or more lines of data from the CSV file and send these lines of data to the WebSocket server as requests, thanks for your help.

[CSV Data Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTMhM.png)

[the WebSocket Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ7g4.png)

Answer (score 0):

CSV Data Set Config reads the next line on each **iteration** of a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or a [Logic Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers), if you want to send several lines within the bounds of a single iteration you need to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) where you have the full freedom with regards to which data to read, when to advance to next line, etc.

So if you have CSV file like:

```
line1-value1,line1-value2
line2-value2,line2-value2
```

you can send 2 lines in a single request like:

```
${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}    ${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}  ${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}
${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}    ${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for your help，but if the CSV file contains Japanese or Chinese language, it can't read any line of the data from the file，I don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: It might be connected with the file encoding. If the file contains Japanese characters - make sure to save it in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding and add `file.encoding=UTF-8` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), this way __CSVRead() function should properly handle Japanese characters. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) and [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)

Comment: I find the solution to the above problem following your suggestion，but the file must be saved in ANSI encoding, otherwise, it still can't read any data from the file!